# how to disable Wayland and use your Ubuntu 22.04 with Xorg?

Tags: ubuntu, wayland

how to disable Wayland and use your Ubuntu 22.04 with Xorg

Answer (score 0):

To disable Wayland and use Xorg on Ubuntu 22.04, you can follow these steps:

Open the terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T
Type

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

to open the GDM3 configuration file
Uncomment the line #WaylandEnable=false by removing the # at the beginning of the line
Save the file by pressing Ctrl+O, then Ctrl+X to exit nano
Restart your system and you should now be using Xorg instead of Wayland.
Or you can use the following command in the terminal :

```
sudo sed -i 's/#WaylandEnable=false/WaylandEnable=false/' /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

And then reboot your system.

Note that you will have to logout and back in for the changes to take effect.

Please be aware that disabling Wayland may cause some problems with graphics and displays, it may be not compatible with some apps, so it is important to test it before you use it in production.